# How to parse JSON results properly

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I am currently working with the [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/), I am doing fetch requests to recieve back the JSON at a given endpoint, then trying to parse and return it. The function for doing this can be found here:

```js
function getPokemon(id){

    pokemonData = {
        name:"",
        image:"",
        id:id,
        description:""
    }
    
    // Documentation https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon-species
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
        
            pokemonData.description = data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text.toString()
            
          }
        )
    
    // Documentation: https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
        
            pokemonData["image"] = data.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default.toString()
            pokemonData["name"] = data.name.toString()
            
          }
        )

    return pokemonData
}
```

Once the data is returned trying to access attributes are blank, but the object displays the correct info:

[image]

I'm not sure what seems to be going wrong here. I have tried every different attribute access format `data.name` vs `data["name"]` and none seem to make a difference. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer is correct in the way that it solves your problem.
But it doesn't fully utilize `async / await` and promises.

Using `await` on both `fetch` calls makes the code run the requests one by one. You can make this faster by letting both `fetch` calls run *in parallel* and wait for both to finish with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

After both requests as are finished, create your `pokemonData` object and return it based on the data from both sets.

```
async function getPokemon(id) {
  const speciesRequest = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    
  const pokemonRequest fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
  
  try {
    const [speciesData, pokemonData] = await Promise.all([speciesRequest, pokemonRequest]);

    return ({
      id,
      image: pokemonData.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default,
      name: pokemonData.name,
      description: speciesData.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text.toString()
    });
  catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of writing this I figured out what was happening. when using `.then()` my understanding was that this also awaited the response and made it synchronous since online resources state this.

**This is not true**.

I had to make my function an async function so that I could await the fetch, since the function was running faster than the fetch could happen. The fixed code is:

```js
async function getPokemon(id){
    
    pokemonData = {
        name:"",
        image:"",
        id:id,
        description:""
    }
    
    // Documentation https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon-species
    await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
        
            pokemonData.description = data.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text.toString()
            
          }
        )
    
    // Documentation: https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon
    await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
        
            pokemonData.image = data.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default
            pokemonData.name = data.name
            console.log(data.name)
            
          }
        )
    return pokemonData
}
```